# Records Won't Insert into Join Table for has_many :through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models: `User` and `Collective`, along with their join table, `Membership`. When a user creates a new collective, I want to simultaneously create a new membership between the two. Right now I have my create function partially working, in that the collective 'new' form adds a collective record to my db but no membership record is added.

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :collectives, :through => :memberships
    has_many :memberships
end
```

**Collective Model**

```
class Collective < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, :through => :memberships
    has_many :memberships
end
```

**Membership Model**

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :collective

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :collective_id, presence: true
end
```

**Collective Controller**

```
def new
    @collective = Collective.new if user_signed_in?
end

def create
    @collective = Collective.new(collective_params)

    if @collective.save
        current_user.memberships.create(collective_id: @collective) 
        flash[:success] = "Collective created!"
        redirect_to collective_url(@collective)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

    def collective_params
        params.require(:collective).permit(:name, :description, :location, :num_of_users, :num_of_projects)
    end

end
```

**Log**

```
Started POST "/collectives" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 10:49:39 -0500
Processing by CollectivesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Dh/rG1N6ulrJSIiEaAgudnaltjxnKwCw5sdUQxG9qnE=", "collective"=>{"name"=>"Honda Civic", "location"=>"Cars", "description"=>"Blaahhhhh"}, "commit"=>"Create Collective"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "collectives" ("created_at", "description", "location", "name", "num_of_projects", "num_of_users", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-11-06 15:49:40.003338"], ["description", "Blaahhhhh"], ["location", "Cars"], ["name", "Honda Civic"], ["num_of_projects", 0], ["num_of_users", 1], ["updated_at", "2014-11-06 15:49:40.003338"]]
   (145.3ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/collectives/7
Completed 302 Found in 208ms (ActiveRecord: 146.7ms)
```

It seems like the line `current_user.memberships.create(collective_id: @collective)` is just being ignored for some reason given that the redirect happens fine. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the log have in it?  To be honest you could just do `@collective = current_user.collectives.new(collective_params)` which would create the association automatically.

Comment: ...or `current_user.collectives << @collective`? Yes, Rails are **that** smart.

Comment: I added the terminal output and interesting. Okay, I'll give that a try but why isn't what I have working? Any thoughts?

Comment: Tried using '@collective = current_user.collectives.new(collective_params)' but no luck in creating a membership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the problem is with passing instance object instead of `id`. It should be:

```
if @collective.save
    current_user.memberships.create(collective_id: @collective.id) 
    flash[:success] = "Collective created!"
    redirect_to collective_url(@collective)
else
    render 'new'
end
```

Since `create` method only returns `true/false` (`false` in this case because of validation) and does not raise any exception, it gets redirected into `show` action.